# NullReferenceException on code that should work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, nullreferenceexception

I have the following controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            Seguimiento seguimiento = repo.GetSeguimiento(id);

            if (seguimiento == null)
            {
                return View("NotFound");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Details", seguimiento);
            }
        }
```

And in the details view:

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Informacion General</legend>

        <p><span class="label-for">ID:</span> <%: Model.ID %></p>

        <p><span class="label-for">Materia:</span> <%: Model.Materia.Nombre %></p>

        <p><span class="label-for">Docente:</span> <%: Model.Materia.Docente.Nombre %></p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Informacion Tiempo</legend>

        <p><span class="label-for">Fecha:</span> <%: String.Format("{0:g}", Model.Dia) %></p>

        <p><span class="label-for">Hora:</span> <%: String.Format("{0:g}", Model.Hora) %></p>

        <p><span class="label-for">Evaluador:</span> <%: Model.Evaluador.Nombre %></p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Desarrollo</legend>

        <p><span class="label-for">Objetivo:</span> <%: Model.Desarrollo.Dominio %> | </p>

        <p><span class="label-for">Objetivo:</span> <%: Model.Desarrollo.Contenido %> | </p>

        <p><span class="label-for">Objetivo:</span> <%: Model.Desarrollo.Organizacion %> |   </p>
    </fieldset>
```

The first two fieldsets work; the last one doesn't.

Dominio, Contenido, Organizacion are bit type is the database, so maybe that's a factor?

Comment: The issue is Desarrollo is null, not the actual field (Dominio, Contenido, Organizacion )

Comment: @Nix - That's a wild guess but I'll bite.

Comment: Isn’t “información” spelled with an acute accent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably the case that `Model.Desarrollo` (or `Model.Materia` or `Model.Evaluador`) is `null`, not `Dominio` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty easy to figure out.  Put a break point in the method and check if the property `Desarollo` is null.  If so, you'll need to modify your view code to account for this (or fix the reason why it is null when it shouldn't be).